# Resize font-size automatically based on the div height & width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need your help please. I am writing on images with absolute containers, take a look here: [jsfiddle.net/z2hmcdt2](http://jsfiddle.net/z2hmcdt2/)

In the data field "data-wanted-height" is always the wanted pixel height, I want for this container. I place 1:x inline container into it.

For example this container:

```html
<div id="fields_item_3" class="fields_item aleft" style="top:140px;left:13px;width:180px;line-height:22px;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;color:#000;" data-wanted-height="22">
  <div class="item">Sample Street 123</div>
  <div class="item spacer">&bull;</div>
  <div class="item">12345</div>
  <div class="item">Sample City</div>
</div>
```

How can I resize the font-size so that it will fit always? No wrap or anything and its irrelevant how long the text will be.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Depending on your options you can use http://fittextjs.com/
Although they go against using it in small text.

Comment: If the answer didnt work or you meant something else, let me know so I can help

Comment: http://fittextjs.com/ dont work for me as I wish. Its resizing not everything. I am currently watching http://chunksnbits.github.io/jquery-quickfit/. Maybe this works. Your answer isnt correct for me, data-wanted-height is the div height I want, not the font-size otherwise i would put it into my style with: font-size:xxxx